# Saving value in a field using Java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a list of callables

```
  KNNQuery<O> knnq; //field
 List<Callable<KNNQuery>> callables = Arrays.asList(
            task1(database, relation),
            task2(database, relation));

    executor.invokeAll(callables)  //List<Future<KNNQery>>
    .stream() //stream<Future<KNNQuery>>
            .map(future -> {
                try{
                    return future.get();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            })  //stream<KNNQuery>
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Instead of printing output of two Futures to the screen i want to combing and save both future's output to the knnq field how can i do that?

Comment: You can use a reduction operation on the stream.

Comment: You want to save two values to a single field? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Actually i have two callables when i iterate through foreach loop and get output from future.get() method. forEach loop first give output of first callable and save it in knnq and then forEach loop give output of second callable and replace the value in variable knnq. Instead of replacing i need both outputs combined. Remember KNNQuery<O> is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You **have to use** a `reducing` operation to combine the stream elements.
A stream collect, that is the transformation of the stream elements into a specific accumulated result (`List`, `Map`, `KNNQuery`, and so for...)  is a reducing operation.

Supposing that `KNNQuery` accepts a `String` parameter as constructor that is `KNNQuery(String value)` and you would like to combine the `KNNQuery` `toString()` value, you could do the following that uses the `Collectors.joining()` reduction  :

```
KNNQuery<O> knnq = 
  new KNNQuery(
        executor.invokeAll(callables)  //List<Future<KNNQery>>
                .stream() //stream<Future<KNNQuery>>
                .map(future -> {
                    try{
                        return future.get();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                 })  
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
             );
```

With `Collectors.reducing()` you would have more freedom to combine `KNNQuery` instances.
For example you could delegate it to a `KNNQuery` method : `KNNQuery combine(KNNQuery other)`.

```
KNNQuery<O> knnq =      
        executor.invokeAll(callables)  //List<Future<KNNQery>>
                .stream() //stream<Future<KNNQuery>>
                .map(future -> {
                    try{
                        return future.get();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                 })  
                .reducing(KNNQuery::combine) // add it to combine two KNNQuery instances
                .orElse(null);
```

Comment: issue with the first example is KNNQuery<O> is an interface can't create its object and issue with second example is no combine() method is giving by default.

Comment: It is an example. As you don't expose how KNNQuery is declared and you don't explain either how you want to combine them I made assumptions and proposed you a generic way that you can implement by adding the `combine` method in your interface.

Comment: instead of java 8 is there any method in java for combining output of two futures?